# Doctrine DBAL increment

Tags: doctrine, dbal

how can I increment a value?

```
$app->db->update('videos', array(
    'views' => 'views + 1'
), array(
    'id' => $id
));
```

It doesn't work in many ways I tried.

Comment: use doctrine query builder http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach could be to use the method [executeUpdate()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#executeupdate)

```
$app->db->executeUpdate("UPDATE videos SET views=views+1 WHERE id=?", array($id));
```

## Edit 2022

The API is working but marked deprecated. Use `executeStatement()` instead of `executeUpdate()`

Answer (score -1):

You have to ask the db for the current value of `views` first, then increment the value and save the new value into db.

```
$result = $app->db->fetchAssoc('SELECT views FROM videos WHERE id = ?', array($id));
$result['views']++;
$app->db->update('videos', array('views' => $result['views']), array('id' => $id));
```

Comment: a `fetchColumn` would be better here, this is the way I solved this.

Comment: this fails in many scenarios, you can update a value with a calculated version of itself - faster performance and a lot safer.